# Find empty column

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I want to find out what column of first row is empty.

```
Call getEmptyColumnFirstRow("E:\file.xlsx")

Function getEmptyColumnFirstRow(path)

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim oApp_Excel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook

Set oApp_Excel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
oApp_Excel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set oBook = oApp_Excel.Workbooks.Open(path)
wks = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim FirstEmptyCol As Long: FirstEmptyCol = wks.Cells.Find(What:="").column

End Function
```

But I got this  error:

> Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: First fix this: `Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet` - Then put a breakpoint on this line `wks = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and see if there is a problem setting that variable. - All of this assumes you have added the Excel reference to AutoCAD VBE and the code is running in AutoCAD.

Comment: Also, missing the `Set` keyword for a worksheet object.  Should be `Set wks = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1")`